# Azure DevOps ARM Template adminPassword Windows VM

Tags: azure, azure-devops, virtual-machine

I am setting up my first ARM template to create a simple windows Virtiual Machine via Azure DevOps.

I have the template file and parameters file and have set a pipeline variable to avoid the complexities of an Azure KeyVault as the first step.

I have setup a pipeline variable Password and locked it.

The Virtual Machine gets setup in my Azure Account no problem but I cannot log in to it.  It will not accept the credentials I am passing in.  If I reset the password using portal.azure.com all is well.  Something is not right about what I am doing in passing my ARM template the adminPassword.

template:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "location": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "networkInterfaceName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "networkSecurityGroupName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "networkSecurityGroupRules": {
            "type": "array"
        },
        "subnetName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "virtualNetworkName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "addressPrefixes": {
            "type": "array"
        },
        "subnets": {
            "type": "array"
        },
        "publicIpAddressName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "publicIpAddressType": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "publicIpAddressSku": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "virtualMachineName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "virtualMachineComputerName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "virtualMachineRG": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "osDiskType": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "dataDisks": {
            "type": "array"
        },
        "dataDiskResources": {
            "type": "array"
        },
        "virtualMachineSize": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "adminUsername": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "adminPassword": {
            "type": "secureString"
        },
        "patchMode": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "nsgId": "[resourceId(resourceGroup().name, 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', parameters('networkSecurityGroupName'))]",
        "vnetId": "[resourceId(resourceGroup().name,'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('virtualNetworkName'))]",
        "subnetRef": "[concat(variables('vnetId'), '/subnets/', parameters('subnetName'))]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "[parameters('networkInterfaceName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
            "apiVersion": "2018-10-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/', parameters('networkSecurityGroupName'))]",
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', parameters('virtualNetworkName'))]",
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses/', parameters('publicIpAddressName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "ipConfigurations": [
                    {
                        "name": "ipconfig1",
                        "properties": {
                            "subnet": {
                                "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
                            },
                            "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                            "publicIpAddress": {
                                "id": "[resourceId(resourceGroup().name, 'Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses', parameters('publicIpAddressName'))]"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "networkSecurityGroup": {
                    "id": "[variables('nsgId')]"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "[parameters('networkSecurityGroupName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
            "apiVersion": "2019-02-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "securityRules": "[parameters('networkSecurityGroupRules')]"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "[parameters('virtualNetworkName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
            "apiVersion": "2019-09-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "addressSpace": {
                    "addressPrefixes": "[parameters('addressPrefixes')]"
                },
                "subnets": "[parameters('subnets')]"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "[parameters('publicIpAddressName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses",
            "apiVersion": "2019-02-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "publicIpAllocationMethod": "[parameters('publicIpAddressType')]"
            },
            "sku": {
                "name": "[parameters('publicIpAddressSku')]"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "[parameters('dataDiskResources')[copyIndex()].name]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/disks",
            "apiVersion": "2020-09-30",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": "[parameters('dataDiskResources')[copyIndex()].properties]",
            "sku": {
                "name": "[parameters('dataDiskResources')[copyIndex()].sku]"
            },
            "copy": {
                "name": "managedDiskResources",
                "count": "[length(parameters('dataDiskResources'))]"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "[parameters('virtualMachineName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
            "apiVersion": "2020-12-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "managedDiskResources",
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', parameters('networkInterfaceName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "hardwareProfile": {
                    "vmSize": "[parameters('virtualMachineSize')]"
                },
                "storageProfile": {
                    "osDisk": {
                        "createOption": "fromImage",
                        "managedDisk": {
                            "storageAccountType": "[parameters('osDiskType')]"
                        }
                    },
                    "imageReference": {
                        "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
                        "offer": "WindowsServer",
                        "sku": "2016-Datacenter",
                        "version": "latest"
                    },
                    "copy": [
                        {
                            "name": "dataDisks",
                            "count": "[length(parameters('dataDisks'))]",
                            "input": {
                                "lun": "[parameters('dataDisks')[copyIndex('dataDisks')].lun]",
                                "createOption": "[parameters('dataDisks')[copyIndex('dataDisks')].createOption]",
                                "caching": "[parameters('dataDisks')[copyIndex('dataDisks')].caching]",
                                "diskSizeGB": "[parameters('dataDisks')[copyIndex('dataDisks')].diskSizeGB]",
                                "managedDisk": {
                                    "id": "[coalesce(parameters('dataDisks')[copyIndex('dataDisks')].id, if(equals(parameters('dataDisks')[copyIndex('dataDisks')].name, json('null')), json('null'), resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/disks', parameters('dataDisks')[copyIndex('dataDisks')].name)))]",
                                    "storageAccountType": "[parameters('dataDisks')[copyIndex('dataDisks')].storageAccountType]"
                                },
                                "writeAcceleratorEnabled": "[parameters('dataDisks')[copyIndex('dataDisks')].writeAcceleratorEnabled]"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "networkProfile": {
                    "networkInterfaces": [
                        {
                            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', parameters('networkInterfaceName'))]"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "osProfile": {
                    "computerName": "[parameters('virtualMachineComputerName')]",
                    "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
                    "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]",
                    "windowsConfiguration": {
                        "enableAutomaticUpdates": true,
                        "provisionVmAgent": true,
                        "patchSettings": {
                            "patchMode": "[parameters('patchMode')]"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "priority": "Spot",
                "evictionPolicy": "Deallocate",
                "billingProfile": {
                    "maxPrice": 0.08
                },
                "diagnosticsProfile": {
                    "bootDiagnostics": {
                        "enabled": true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {
        "adminUsername": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[parameters('adminUsername')]"
        }
    }
}
```

parameters.json:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "location": {
            "value": "uksouth"
        },
        "networkInterfaceName": {
            "value": "machine1587"
        },
        "networkSecurityGroupName": {
            "value": "Machine1-nsg"
        },
        "networkSecurityGroupRules": {
            "value": [
                {
                    "name": "RDP",
                    "properties": {
                        "priority": 300,
                        "protocol": "TCP",
                        "access": "Allow",
                        "direction": "Inbound",
                        "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                        "sourcePortRange": "*",
                        "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                        "destinationPortRange": "3389"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "subnetName": {
            "value": "default"
        },
        "virtualNetworkName": {
            "value": "AzureTest-vnet"
        },
        "addressPrefixes": {
            "value": [
                "10.0.0.0/24"
            ]
        },
        "subnets": {
            "value": [
                {
                    "name": "default",
                    "properties": {
                        "addressPrefix": "10.0.0.0/24"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "publicIpAddressName": {
            "value": "Machine1-ip"
        },
        "publicIpAddressType": {
            "value": "Dynamic"
        },
        "publicIpAddressSku": {
            "value": "Basic"
        },
        "virtualMachineName": {
            "value": "Machine1"
        },
        "virtualMachineComputerName": {
            "value": "Machine1"
        },
        "virtualMachineRG": {
            "value": "AzureTest"
        },
        "osDiskType": {
            "value": "Standard_LRS"
        },
        "dataDisks": {
            "value": [
                {
                    "lun": 0,
                    "createOption": "attach",
                    "caching": "ReadOnly",
                    "writeAcceleratorEnabled": false,
                    "id": null,
                    "name": "Machine1_DataDisk_0",
                    "storageAccountType": null,
                    "diskSizeGB": null,
                    "diskEncryptionSet": null
                }
            ]
        },
        "dataDiskResources": {
            "value": [
                {
                    "name": "Machine1_DataDisk_0",
                    "sku": "Standard_LRS",
                    "properties": {
                        "diskSizeGB": 64,
                        "creationData": {
                            "createOption": "empty"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "virtualMachineSize": {
            "value": "Standard_DS1_v2"
        },
        "adminUsername": {
            "value": "LocalAdminUserName"
        },
        "adminPassword": {
            "value": null
        },
        "patchMode": {
            "value": "AutomaticByOS"
        }
    }
}
```

[image: DevOps Release Pipeline]

[image: DevOps Variable]

```
steps:
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  displayName: 'ARM Template deployment: Resource Group scope'
  inputs:
    azureResourceManagerConnection: 'Pay-As-You-Go (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)'
    subscriptionId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    resourceGroupName: AzureTest
    location: 'UK South'
    csmFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Azure/First Virtual Machine/template.json'
    csmParametersFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Azure/First Virtual Machine/parameters.json'
    overrideParameters: '-adminPassword "$(Password)"'
```

Answer (score 0):

That all looks fine on the surface, but your template schema is no longer on the supported schemas list for `virtualMachines` at [Resource Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/allversions). I'm wondering if you might get traction with a later template version?

Comment: Interesting, since the template was downloaded from the portal UI final step.

Comment: I'm not positive it's part of the problem, but it did stand out to me. I wouldn't be the first time that YAML schema and/or its documentation were out of date.